# How to run SQL execute command in flyway

Tags: procedure, flyway

I need to execute a procedure from flyway. When I run it Is failing stating that invalid SQL statement. Can someone please help me to how I can exexute a procedure from flyway.

Command: EXECUTE

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL*Plus command and not a SQL command. You can use it by activating Flyway's SQL*Plus support by setting `flyway.oracle.sqlplus`to `true`. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#oracle.sqlplus

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it inside begin/end on your sql file?

```
BEGIN
    your_procedure;
END;
```